# Android kotlin / java - logout: clear shared preferences and stop all processes in background

Tags: java, android, kotlin

After I clear all shared preferences and send the user to main activity:

```
            this.getSharedPreferences("userData", 0).edit().clear().apply()


            finishAffinity()
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
```

The app crashes becauzse there are still couple of tasks/timers in the background associated with the preferences. How can you just finish EVERYTHING before I send the user to main activity?

I tried this:

```
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
            startActivity(intent)
```

but it just put the app into background and after I getting it back to foreground it crashes. Is there any solution to just stop everything and start specific activity without finishing all background tasks one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can try commit() instead of apply() and get the return value whether all data cleared successfully!

Here is the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor).

Comment: Nah the problem is that there are tasks in the background which read the preferences that's why the app crashes after I clear them. I need to find a way to stop all tasks/processes no matter in which activity and without completely closing the app

Answer (score 0):

```
getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .clear()
            .apply()

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            finishAffinity()
        }
```

make sure "useData" is the same when you were saving the data.